# Asp.net core mailkit

Tags: asp.net, email, azure

I have Asp.net core web application and for sending email using Mailkit:

```
            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("John", "john@outlook.com"));
            emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Doe", email));
            emailMessage.Subject = subject;
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = message };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
                client.Connect("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587, false);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                client.Authenticate("john@outlook.com", "password");
                client.Send(emailMessage);
                client.Disconnect(true);
            }
```

While running application localy on VS it's sending fine. But when i upload it to Azure App Service on sending email it's failing with such message:

```
SmtpProtocolException: The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected.

MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadAhead(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.SendCommand(string command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Authenticate(Encoding encoding, ICredentials credentials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
MailKit.MailService.Authenticate(string userName, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure does not allow for outbound connections on port 25 and also blocks all outbound SMTP except for when connecting to SendGrid, a third-party SMTP provider who are the single "blessed" outbound email provider for Microsoft Azure.

(I think this is odd because you'd think Microsoft would want to show-off their Exchange services in Azure, as well as competing with AWS' e-mail service)

SendGrid is free (fortunately - otherwise that would be extortion) up to 20,000 e-mails a month, after then they're still pretty cheap.

You can create a SendGrid account from within Azure Portal directly, then click the "Manage" button to open your SendGrid account details and get their SMTP details, including username and password.

SendGrid offers two APIs: the first is just a raw "dumb" SMTP service, though by default they will delay your emails by 10 minutes (to mitigate spam) until your account is deemed "trusted". Their second API is a HTTP web-service you can use - this is better for heavy-load scenarios because HTTP connections are cheaper than SMTP connections.

Comment: hi Dai, thanks for your explanation. So does it mean that we cannot use Mailkit on Azure for ASP.NET Core?